# How to redirect programatically using a route with parameters?

Tags: 8, redirection

I am trying to use the Passwordless module API to redirect the user on login.

I want to redirect the user to a specific node edit page (**node/12/edit**).

In `hook_passwordless_login_redirect()`, the module redirects the user with this code:

`return $this->redirect($redirect);`

So here is my implementation:

```
function MYMODULE_passwordless_login_redirect_alter(&$redirect) {
  // You can use hasPermission() with currentUser, but need to load for hasRole()
  $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\user::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $test = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid('node/12/edit');
  if (!($account->hasRole('admin'))) {
    $redirect= $test->getRouteName();
  }
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("node") to generate a URL for
>   route "entity.node.edit_form".

The missing route parameter is the node id, which I can get with `$test->getRouteParameters()`.  But how do I pass this to the redirect?  (How do I call the redirect and give it both the route name and the route parameters?)

Comment: This module is probably using [UrlGeneratorTrait::redirect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorTrait.php/function/UrlGeneratorTrait%3A%3Aredirect/8.4.x). Then you are out of luck, because the route parameters are the second parameter, which is not offered in the alter hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @4k4, the problem is that the module did not ask for the route parameters, so I [patched it](https://www.drupal.org/node/2641148#comment-12330970).

Then you can call the redirect like this:

```
  if (!($account->hasRole('admin'))) {
    $routename = $test->getRouteName();
    $routeparameters= $test->getRouteParameters();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters like below:

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute(
    $test->getRouteName(),
     array(
       'query' => array('query1' => 'YOUR QUERY'),
       'absolute' => TRUE,
     )
);
```